# URL Re-writing using web.confg

Tags: url, url-rewriting, web-config

This is what I'm trying to achieve using web.config (My current web.config is used to force non-www which will still be needed)

The site was first hosted under a sub-folder and we moved it now to the root. This is what I'm trying to achieve now:

old url example: mysite.com/subfolder/prodView.asp?idproduct=1312&idCategory=44  should get redirected to  mysite.com/prodView.asp?idproduct=1312&idCategory=44  (We need to get rid of the old subfolder)

This is will be needed as many customer have already saved products link in their browsers and also we posted 1000's on links on twitter and facebook that all include the sub-folder within.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

```
Current web.config
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
<rewrite>
<rules>
<rule name="Remove WWW prefix" stopProcessing="false">
<match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="true" />
<conditions>
<add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www\.mysite\.com$" />
</conditions>
<action type="Redirect" url="http://mysite.com/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
</rules>
</rewrite>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following rule to your existing rule(s):

```
<rule name="Redirect old subfolder links" stopProcessing="false">
  <match url="^subfolder/(.+)" ignoreCase="true" />
  <action type="Redirect" url="/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```